# Pandas grouping by column and column variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'type':['emph','emph', 'tr', 'tf', 'jitt', 'loss'],
                   'result':[1,1,2,3,4,5]})
```

[image]

I would like the groupby to group by the type column but join the tr and tf groups together into a new group trtf:

[image]

When I groupby("type") of course i get separate groups for tr and tf and I cant see how to specify grouping based on a column variable name.

I dont mind if Tr and Tf get preserved in the output as long as a new group TrTf is created.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you show code where  you "When I groupby("type")" ?

Comment: Sure: df.groupby(['type'])['result'].describe()[['min','mean','max']]

Comment: Is possible remove `tr` , `tf` from output and let only `trtf` ?

Comment: Two advices for future: a) try not to use image files when it's possible to use text, b) if you use images - use `<img src=">` for them

Comment: Sure Alex will do. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Create list of tuples for values groups together, then dictionary and last [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) column `type` in `groupby` with `sum`:

```
L = [('tr','tf'), ('a','b')]
d = {y:''.join(x) for x in L for y in x}
print (d)
{'tr': 'trtf', 'tf': 'trtf', 'a': 'ab', 'b': 'ab'}

df = df.groupby(df['type'].replace(d))['result'].sum().reset_index()
print (df)
   type  result
0  emph       2
1  jitt       4
2  loss       5
3  trtf       5
```

---

If is possible grouping by first letter use [`DataFrameGroupBy.agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) with `sum` and `join` with `set`s:

```
df = (df.groupby(df['type'].str[0])
        .agg({'result':'sum', 'type':lambda x: ''.join(set(x))})
        .reset_index(drop=True))
print (df)
   result  type
0       2     A
1       5  B1B2
2       4     C
3       5     D
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['type'].str[0])
0    A
1    A
2    B
3    B
4    C
5    D
Name: type, dtype: object
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks so much for all your responses